# RFC822 compliant SMTP address

Tags: smtp, exchange-server-2010, rfc822

I'm getting mixed answers on whether the following SMTP address is RFC822 compliant:

```
"Jane Doe" <jane.doe@acme.com>
```

Is the above format compliant or should it only be:

```
jane.doe@acme.com
```

?

Looked at the following address specification from RFC822:

```
   6.  ADDRESS SPECIFICATION

 6.1.  SYNTAX

 address     =  mailbox                      ; one addressee
             /  group                        ; named list

 group       =  phrase ":" [#mailbox] ";"

 mailbox     =  addr-spec                    ; simple address
             /  phrase route-addr            ; name & addr-spec

 route-addr  =  "<" [route] addr-spec ">"

 route       =  1#("@" domain) ":"           ; path-relative

 addr-spec   =  local-part "@" domain        ; global address

 local-part  =  word *("." word)             ; uninterpreted
                                             ; case-preserved

 domain      =  sub-domain *("." sub-domain)

 sub-domain  =  domain-ref / domain-literal

 domain-ref  =  atom                         ; symbolic reference
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both email addresses are valid, for further email address RFC822 compliance checks please use the below tool.

http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~pdw/cgi-bin/emailvalidate

**Update**

The RFC822 was obsoleted by RFC2822 to check RFC2822 use

http://proxy2.de/email-validation.php

**EDIT**

Thanks @jstedfast, The above link validates RFC5322 as well.

Comment: And rfc2822 was obsoleted by rfc5322.